# Laravel : Integrity constraint violation: Column cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-query-builder

i'm trying to update event name through `postman` with the following `json` object:

```
PUT {{base_url}}events/1 
{
    "name":"this Event Name is Edited"
}
```

in my controller i'm using `sometimes` constraint because not all fields must be updated, it could be only 1 field like `name`, and after that i update the event with `update` method

`EventController.php`

```
    public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'sometimes|string|max:255',
            'description'=>'nullable|string',
            'start_time' => 'sometimes|date',
            'end_time'=> 'sometimes|date|after:start_time',
       ]);

        return $event->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'start_time' => $request->start_time,
            'end_time' => $request->end_time
        ]);
    }
```

when i request it gives me error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: Column start_time cannot be null
```

so the `sometimes` constraint doesn't seem to work here, what could be the problem

Comment: it is telling you the problem: `start_time` can not be `null` ... you will need to check to see if that field is even present/has a value before trying to add it to your array for the update (in this case)

Comment: `so the sometimes constraint doesn't seem to work here`, [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present) is condition validation, it applies only when a field is present in the data being validated and doesn't prevent the field from being considered absent if it is present but has a null value. You can try `'start_time' => 'sometimes|nullable|date'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the data after validation:

```
public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $payload = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'string|max:255',
        'description'=>'nullable|string',
        'start_time' => 'date',
        'end_time'=> 'date|after:start_time',
    ]);

    return $event->update($payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the data being validated. To quickly accomplish this, add the **sometimes** rule to your rule list.

Please check your database or migration file, check start_date fields is nullable or not? if nullable then you can validate  this way  `'start_time' => 'sometimes|date'` if start_date fields is required then you should must validate this way `'start_time' => 'required|date'`.

If start_date fields is required update your code this way

```
public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'sometimes|string|max:255',
        'description'=>'nullable|string',
        'start_time' => 'required|date',
        'end_time'=> 'date|after:start_time',
    ]);

    return $event->update($data);
}
```